# Remove a list item onclick a picture with javascript

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I have a positioned div which contains a list. I have a bunch of buttons attached to pictures which correspond to the words on the list. I have two related issues. Firstly the list itself is too long for the space provided so I need to hide parts of it. That's ok if I can get the second issue to work. The second issue is getting rid of items after their corresponding picture has been clicked on. So if I click on the picture of a chair. The word "Chair" disappears from the list and the rest of the list below it moves up into it's space. Preferably I want this to happen onclick, but I can't work out how to accomplish it.

This is my list

```
    <div class="absolute2">
<div class="translist">
<ul>
    <li id="penina">5 penina</li>
    <li id="pua">5 pua</li>
    <li id="salulima">Salu lima</li>
    <li id="manulele">Manulele</li>
    <li id="fatu">Fatu</li>
    <li id="ialapoa">I‘a lāpo‘a</li>
    <li id="gata">Gata</li>
    <li id="lima">Lima</li>
    <li id="pili">Pili</li>
    <li id="aveau">‘Aveau</li>
    <li id="uati">Uati</li>
    <li id="vaaroketi">Va‘a rōketi</li>
    <li id="masinamoana">Māsina moana</li>
 </ul>   
</div>
</div>
```

and this is one of the buttons

```
    <td rowspan="3" colspan="4"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','navbar2','n_r2_c8','images/_r2_c8_s2.jpg',1); cutList(manulele); incrementValue(); this.onclick=null;"><img name="n_r2_c8" src="images/_r2_c8.jpg" width="53" height="47" id="n_r2_c8" alt="" /></a></td>
```

This button should get rid of the list item "Manulele"
I haven't tried much, because all the solutions I can find are jquery, and I can't use jquery. Below is what I'm trying unsuccessfully with various variations. Please assist.

```
function cutList(itemid) {
  var element = document.getElementById( itemid );
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

Comment: Don't you get a `ReferenceError` with `elemen`? Or maybe is it a typo?

Comment: typo, will fix it now, cheers

Comment: I see `manulele` is passed on the click event in the HTML, but what is its value, and how does it change?

Comment: it's the id of the list item, each button passes a different one which goes with the list item id's, which is where (I think) I'm going wrong with my function.

Comment: why not attach the same `id`, which `li` is having, on the `img` and then onclick pass `this.id` to your `cutList` function.

Comment: @RohitKumar  I just tried it, didn't work, do I need to change the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me, may it be a problem of the previous functions called on the click. Try the snippet, isn't it what you wanted?

```js
function cutList(itemid) {
  var element = document.getElementById( itemid );
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

```html
 <div class="absolute2">
<div class="translist">
<ul>
    <li id="penina">5 penina</li>
    <li id="pua">5 pua</li>
    <li id="salulima">Salu lima</li>
    <li id="manulele">Manulele</li>
    <li id="fatu">Fatu</li>
    <li id="ialapoa">I‘a lāpo‘a</li>
    <li id="gata">Gata</li>
    <li id="lima">Lima</li>
    <li id="pili">Pili</li>
    <li id="aveau">‘Aveau</li>
    <li id="uati">Uati</li>
    <li id="vaaroketi">Va‘a rōketi</li>
    <li id="masinamoana">Māsina moana</li>
 </ul>   
</div>
</div>
<button onclick="cutList('manulele')">Remove</button>
```

Comment: ok, I'm trying to work it out, all the other functions seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap manulele in quotes

```
 cutList('manulele');
```

It works

Comment: if I do that, the button won't click, if I wrap with apostrophe it does click, but doesn't remove the list item. Do I need to change the function at all?

Comment: @epascarello you're right, OP must to learn anyway about strings and concatenation

Comment: @Kilisi Any errors in the console? It should work from what I see